# htaccess rewrite rule. Rewrite URLs not starting with /en to /en/*

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using htaccess mod_rewrite I want to rewrite any URL not starting with example.com/en to /en/*

For example

```
example.com/about-us
```

to

```
example.com/en/about-us
```

I've tried a few simple solutions like

```
RewriteRule !^en/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a negative lookahead regex:

```
RewriteRule ^((?!en/).*)$ /en/$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Another option:

```
RewriteRule !^en/ /en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```