# How do I host my website with the index file being in a subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, url

I would like to host my website from `/src/index.html`
So if you visit my website at `https://example.com`, you will see the contents of `/src/index.html` (without adding `/src/index.html` to the url)

This is currently my file structure

[image: file structure]

I tried adding the following in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^ src/index.html
```

That redirects correctly but also redirects all paths linking to any other files (like style.css) to src/index.html making them unusable.

Something like the following would work but it would change the url to `example.com/src/index.html` while I would like it to stay at `example.com`:

```
Redirect 301 /index.html /src/index.html
```

Comment: _"Something like the following would work"_ - but only for your root URL; if you then wanted to go to anything inside the history subfolder, you would have to link directly to `/src/history/...` again.

Comment: Only thing that I could see working here, is if you checked that the requested URL did not start with `/assets/`, and then rewrite everything into the `src` folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35948681/1427878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^ src/index.html
> ```

This naturally rewrites everything. To rewrite requests for the root only then you need to match against `^$` instead.

For example:

```
 RewriteRule ^$ src/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put your project elsewhere, outside of `DocumentRoot`, and make a softlink (`ln -s`) to your `src` folder in `DocumentRoot`.

If you want your project to be the top level (as in your example, `http://example.com/`), then you can directly set `DocumentRoot` to your `src` folder, or replace the `DocumentRoot` folder with a softlink as described above.

Comment: Directly setting the `DocumentRoot` to the `src` folder wouldn't work since it still needs the files in the `assets` folder which it can't access that way. Your solution of putting my project in another file and creating a symlink to the src folder however worked!

Comment: Nevermind, my website now can't load the files in the assets folder. This solution has the same problem as directly settings the `DocumentRoot` to the `src` folder

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the asset folder. But it is strange — what would be the URL of your assets? How are you trying to access them? Since `http://example.com/../assets/` does not make any sense. Once you specify what URLs should map to what files, it should be easier to come to a solution.

Comment: From my index.html file I access some svgs like `../assets/logos/xxx` for example

Comment: As I said, this is not possible. Forget what is on the file system: from the _URL point of view_, there is no `..` from `http://example.com/`. What _absolute_ URL do you expect `assets/logos/xxx` to sit at?